# Is it proper to say, "our mind" or "our minds" as each person has one mind; or is it considered collectively?

Tags: grammatical-number

Is it proper to say, "our mind" or "our minds"?  Each person has one mind, which causes me to lean towards "our mind".  However, collectively, more than one person has more than one mind (generally speaking), which causes me to favor "our minds".

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give us the full sentence in which _our mind(s)_ is to appear. There is a similar question here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301625/theyre-using-a-cell-phone-vs-theyre-using-cell-phones

Comment: What on earth do you mean by "more than one person has more than one mind"? Every person has exactly one mind, so "minds" is what you want. If it was a collective (think the Borg), and one of them spoke on the subject, they'd say "*our* mind". As in "our mind is far superior to yours."

Comment: By gosh, our minds are made up.

Comment: 'We are minded to grant the applicant the post.' 'The panel is minded to apply for the grant'. You could argue that this really means 'like-minded'. Or, as commented below, 'we are of one mind'. Note: 'We have the mind of Christ' I Corinthians 2:16 [KJV],

Comment: You need to provide some kind of context. What kind of complete sentence did you have in mind? (1) *Our **minds** are made up.* (2) *We are of one **mind**.* (3) *Our (group) **mind** is set on its purpose.*

Comment: Depends on where you apply the noun. Teaching yoga, I would ask students to "roll onto your back" because no one can roll onto plural backs. Speaking to each student in the second person, each 'you' had one back.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Our bodies' or our body's](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12750/our-bodies-or-our-bodys)

Answer (score 1):

In general each person has a mind ("a mind of their own") and so when talking about many people there are many minds involved. You should use the plural.

> Our minds were drawn to the pictures on the wall.

The only time we should use the singular is when we are talking about an organized group that is considered to think and take decisions as a unit - for example a panel of judges, or a prize committee.

> After we have considered all the evidence, our mind is made up and the defendant is found guilty.

Comment: Also to say we are of one mind ....

Comment: I disagree with some of what you say. While I can't think of a situation other than the one you mention where 'our mind' really works, it is common for the individual to be referenced when a disparate audience is being addressed: 'Send off for our new Relacksa-bed, and if you should change your mind, just return it within one month for a full refund.' / 'Take the biscuit base out of the fridge ...'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I see your example as being addressed to each member of the audience individually, and that is why it is singular. You write "just return it" (singular) when really many are sent out.

Comment: 'In general each relevant person has a new Relacksa-bed and so when talking about many people there are many beds involved. You should use the plural.'?